# GT 630 Nvidia card HDMI sound stops working on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, sound, hdmi

Ok I've read all the other post similar to mine and is not the same case so I will present the one I have.

My video card is a **Nvidia 630GT** configured with the **.xorg drivers** it was working properly until today, connected to my 32" TV HDMI, I discovered that the audio wasn't working through the HMDI out but it does by the analog audio out of the motherboard, I also have win xp aside the U14.04 and works fine there.

Any ideas what can I do about it?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **pavucontrol** (pulseaudio volume control, install if necessary).
Launch it from multimedia menu, go to the "output devices" tab, and click the green "define as alternative" button that is near HDMI soundcard.

If it still doesn't work, look also "configuration" tab and change profile.

Comment: Thank you installed what you told me, working again, but now the native sistem volume seems to no response when I use the mouse well to up and down the volume for the system, do you know how to fix this? and you will get +1000 internets for resolving both problems, any way thanks.

Comment: It seems that native volume is commanding the last output device which  "green button"  has been clicked  in pavucontrol.